# Firebase queryOrderByChild in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My data structure looks like this

```
 users:
      -UID1
           -username: username1
           -region: north east 
           -carModel: mustang
```

I am trying to write a search query that queries all users by the current user region. Here is my function for this.

```
    func fetchUsersByRegion() {

        guard let userRegion = self.region else { return } 

        let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").queryOrder(byChild: "region").queryEqual(toValue: userRegion)

        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            guard let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] else { return }

            for snap in snapshot {

                FIRDatabase.fetchUserWithUID(uid: snap.key, completion: { (user) in
                    self.users.append(user)
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                })
            }
        })
```

The snapshot I get back only gives me a limited number of values for the region I query by. It looks like its only when it has the same value for the "region" key consecutively. So if the database contained two user nodes in a row with the region north east, it only gives me back that as a snapshot, when there are multiple other vales with that particular region.

Is there a way to query by a particular region, and get back all of the users in  a snapshot that have that particular region? I ended up doing a fan out to solve the problem, was just wondering if there was a way to do it with queryOrder(byChild: )

Comment: Instead of saving region as a string in your DB you could try using numbers, then on the client parse the numbers to textual regions. I'm pretty sure in this case, query ordered by child on the region node will return based on alphabetical order. Why not use north as 1, north-east as 2, east as 3, ... north-west as 7 ... see how that works.

Comment: very good idea! ill give that a shot, thank you

Comment: @EliWhittle made a great point and it is definitely a better way. I just have to add, that if I were making that, I would create a separate array just for regions. So have `regions:` > `"REGION_KEY": North East`, etc. And in the users, region would hold a value of `REGION_KEY`. Just a thought, hope it helps. :)